# VB.net Writing XML from Array

Tags: arrays, xml, vb.net, object

i have a simple class

```
Public Class Employee

        Public _id As Integer
        Public _firstName As String
        Public _lastName As String
        Public _location As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal firstName As String, ByVal lastName As String, location As String)
            _id = id
            _firstName = firstName
            _lastName = lastName
            _location = location
        End Sub

    End Class
```

I have defined some example Data:

```
Dim Employees(2) As Employee
        Employees(0) = New Employee(42, "John", "Smith", "NewYork")
        Employees(1) = New Employee(64, "John2", "Smith2", "Budapest")
        Employees(2) = New Employee(62, "John3", "Smith3", "NewYork")
```

I want to write it to XML file as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <NewYork>
    <Employee>
      <ID>42</ID>
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <ID>62</ID>
      <FirstName>John3</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith3</LastName>
    </Employee>
  </NewYork>
  <Budapest>
    <Employee>
      <ID>64</ID>
      <FirstName>Jonh2</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith2</LastName>
    </Employee>
  </Budapest>
</Employees>
```

For writing the XML i have current the following code:

```
Sub XMLWrite()

        Dim Employees(2) As Employee
        Employees(0) = New Employee(42, "John", "Smith", "NewYork")
        Employees(1) = New Employee(64, "John2", "Smith2", "Budapest")
        Employees(2) = New Employee(62, "John3", "Smith3", "NewYork")

        ' Create XmlWriterSettings.
        Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Indent = True

        ' Create XmlWriter.
        Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\employees.xml", settings)
            ' Begin writing.
            writer.WriteStartDocument()
            writer.WriteStartElement("Employees") ' Root.
            writer.WriteStartElement("NewYork")
            Dim empl As Employee
            For Each empl In Employees

                If empl._location = "NewYork" Then
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Employee")
                    writer.WriteElementString("ID", empl._id.ToString)
                    writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", empl._firstName)
                    writer.WriteElementString("LastName", empl._lastName)

                    writer.WriteEndElement()
                End If
            Next
            writer.WriteEndElement()

            writer.WriteStartElement("Budapest")



            Dim empl2 As Employee
            For Each empl2 In Employees
                If empl2._location = "Budapest" Then
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Employee")
                    writer.WriteElementString("ID", empl2._id.ToString)
                    writer.WriteElementString("FirstName", empl2._firstName)
                    writer.WriteElementString("LastName", empl2._lastName)

                    writer.WriteEndElement()
                End If

            Next


            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndDocument()


        End Using


    End Sub
```

I have more then 1000 Users with 30+ Locations, i dont want to define each location manually in the code. I want to transform it, the code should identify the location, and create the xml element under the right location parent element. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. What do you expect us to do? Please specify your question. Show what you have tried so far and point out where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Using xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Employees(2) As Employee
        Employees(0) = New Employee(42, "John", "Smith", "NewYork")
        Employees(1) = New Employee(64, "John2", "Smith2", "Budapest")
        Employees(2) = New Employee(62, "John3", "Smith3", "NewYork")


        Dim header As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Employees></Employees>"

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(header)
        Dim root As XElement = doc.Root
        Dim bornGroups = Employees.GroupBy(Function(x) x.born).ToList()

        For Each group In bornGroups
            Dim newCity As XElement = New XElement(group.Key)
            root.Add(newCity)

            For Each _employee In group
                Dim newEmployee As XElement = New XElement("Employee", New List(Of XElement)({ _
                   New XElement("ID", _employee.id),
                   New XElement("FirstName", _employee.firstName),
                   New XElement("LastName", _employee.lastName)
                   }))
                newCity.Add(newEmployee)
            Next _employee

        Next group
    End Sub

End Module


Public Class Employee
    Public id As Integer
    Public firstName As String
    Public lastName As String
    Public born As String

    Sub New(id As Integer, firstName As String, lastName As String, born As String)
        Me.id = id
        Me.firstName = firstName
        Me.lastName = lastName
        Me.born = born
    End Sub


End Class
```